# Reference for phClr in openxml

Tags: openxml, color-scheme

I am trying to find value for `phClr`, but no results.
Slide master is not having mapping for `phClr`.
I am aware that `phClr` is just a passed-in color value, but what exactly is its color reference?
Is it bg2 or anything else?

Comment: yes i am still searching for correct answer. During this search found that we get reference from slide files in <p:bg> tag which indicates whose value to use from theme file clrscheme for bgFillStyle. But again still not sure. Are there any more places to get value for phClr?

Comment: please post the answer when you find it...

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964302(v=office.12).aspx

> Blockquote
>   The scheme color value is set to placeholder color (the value phClr). This value appears throughout the fill, line, effect, and background styles and indicates that the settings are applied to the theme color applicable for a given style. This allows the same fill, line, and effect styles to populate across the theme colors that appear in the OfficeArt galleries.

“phClr” is a kind of placeholder color